# How to get coordinates of all layer points in adobe illustator?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

How to get coordinates of all layer points in adobe illustator? Seems, I have to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I did this script that extract the coordinates of all selected objects:

http://scriptographer.org/scripts/general-scripts/extractcoords/